# Struts2 dynamic url action in IBM Portal

Tags: jsp, url, dynamic, struts2, action

I'm trying to create a dynamic menu bar using struts2 url tag. I got the list of menus from webservice and try to generate corresponding URL to each menu.
I tried this code

```
<s:iterator value="roleMenus" id="child">
<s:if test="parentCode == #parent.childCode">
    <s:if test="childCode != #parent.childCode">
        <c:set var="link"><s:property value='menuLink'/></c:set>
        <% menulink = (String)pageContext.getAttribute("link"); 
            System.out.println(menulink);%>
        <li><a id='<s:property value="menuLink"/>' name="menulink" href="<s:url action='xxxxx'/>"><s:property value="menuName"/></a></li>
    </s:if>
</s:if>
```

with Action attribute value passed in scriptlet

```
<%=menuLink%>
```

or JSTL variable

```
${link}
```

but it throws an exception

```
According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute "[action]" does not accept any expressions.
```

so I guess this cannot be done using any kind of dynamic expressions in Action attribute.

I'm thinking of overriding the method that generates URL when s:url tag get called but I don't have a clue how to do that. It generates urls like this in IBM Portal:

```
/wps/myportal/!ut/p/b1/jZDbToNAFEW_pR9gzhmG6-OEyMVhUGCowAsh2BiQS6yI0q-X9qkm1va87WSt7J0DBeTE1C2dWhrVIYNiqObmtZqacai6Yy70MmSpw9mTio9oOujHWkKpESnoHoX8HEBCcAU8LVWEUNZ4m2-7zFONANEMXA195qWxFVGKjF7zn6H4jfyx4AT8V3EC8MIxhNAb-x3kK2Zc3GIiZHOz-4LtMO779XUSMlTLpF3GT56ME3_J94ttvi_p24T1HEoctu1yCKRNs28tFtI2Hg6ilC2JCLO7KKxbkWA_obgj3Knvmctn7n9soC86x_JbNffZ5gdG203G/dl4/d5/L0lDU0NtbUEhL3dPb0JKaVVNcHJDSy80RzNhRFVRZy9aN19OQVVGS0FQNDBPMDhGMElSNVMzMzdRMjA4MC8lMHZpZXclMEFwcExvZw!!/
```

Does anyone have any ideas for this? Any help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is sample example to generate dynamic url. I hope this helps you.

```
<s:set name="days" value="{'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday','thrusday','friday' }" />

<s:iterator var="day" value="#days">
    <s:url action="%{#day}" var="urlTag"></s:url>
    <s:property value="%{urlTag}"/><br/>
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: There is an error "JSPG0123E: Unable to locate tag attribute info for tag attribute var." I tried **id** instead of **var** and get another one in web server log "Could not find action %{#day}". I think it definitely doesn't accept expression in **action** attribute. Thanks anw m8.

Comment: The id attribute is deprecated in Struts 2.1.x, and has been replaced by the var attribute.   http://struts.apache.org/2.3.7/docs/iterator.html

Comment: Your code seems to work after I upgrade struts to newest version 2.3.8. But there are some errors I still can't handle while upgrading my framework. Thank you very much.